# PHP + jQuery change background based on server time

Tags: php, jquery

I have an Apache based server, which currently hosts my PHP + HTML5 app. I wrote a jquery script, which should change background image of specific div, if some conditions regarding server time are met. Problem is - the script is not working :)

I've already red some issues here, and tried to fix script, but those didn't help, because they are not completely related to my problem.

Ok, here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var serverdate = new Date("<?php echo date('l,g,i,s'); ?>");
var currentTime = serverdate.getTime();
var gameTime = getTimeFromString("8:45 pm");
var endTime = getTimeFromString("11:45 pm");
var currentDay = serverdate.getDay();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";
    if (currentDay === "Tuesday" || currentDay ==="Wednesday"){
    if (currentTime<gameTime) {
    $('#bodymain').addClass('day').removeClass('game');
    }

else if (currentTime>endTime) {
    $('#bodymain').addClass('day').removeClass('game');
}

else {
    $('#bodymain').addClass('game').removeClass('day');
}
}
else {
$('#bodymain').addClass('day').removeClass('game');
}

function getTimeFromString(timeString){
var theTime = new Date();
var time = timeString.match(/(\d+)(?::(\d\d))?\s*(p?)/);
theTime.setHours(parseInt(time[1])+(time[3]?12:0));
theTime.setMinutes(parseInt(time[2]) || 0);
return theTime.getTime();
}

});
```

Any clues?

Comment: is there a particular reason, why don't you render the image right from php?

Comment: @ Wayne Whitty: No errors, will try dimpala's solution.
@ Michal Klouda: I use this classes elsewhere, and it's easier for me to just use existing class.

Comment: Just so you know Javascript runs client side so you are not getting the server time but the client's time.

Comment: @ Pitchinnate: Not true, <?php echo date('l,g,i,s'); ?>

Comment: PHP's `date()` function is run on the server BEFORE the page leaves the server.  JavaScript's date calculations are begun on the client's device AFTER the page is loaded in the visitor's browser.

Comment: Andrew, read my answer below. I've used different aproach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to use a different approach, based on your inputs. Now it all works flawlessly. Here's the final solution (I had to wait until I could answer my own question):

PHP file:

```
 <?php
$current_time = strtotime('now');
if ($current_time > strtotime('tuesday this week 8:45pm') && $current_time < strtotime('tuesday this week 11:45pm')) {
 $background = 1;
}
else if ($current_time > strtotime('wednesday this week 8:45pm') && $current_time < strtotime('wednesday this week 11:45pm')) {
 $background = 1;
}
else{
$background = 0;
}

?>

<script>
var backday = <?php echo json_encode($background); ?>;
</script>
```

JS File:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
createBackground()

});

function createBackground(){

if (backday === 0) {
$('#bodymain').addClass('day').removeClass('game');
}
else if (backday === 1) {
$('#bodymain').addClass('game').removeClass('day');
}
else {
alert("Background error");

}
}
```

Comment: Do you really need javascript for it? Why not just `<body class="<?php  echo $background ? 'game' : 'day'?>">`

Comment: Because, as I said before, I'm already using this classes for other stuff, and this is not the only code in my javascript file, I've just stripped it down to make it understandable. P.S. My goal was not to change the class for the whole body, just one div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with [serverdate.getDay();](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp).

Date.getDay(); return 0-6 number of day ,not the name of the day.

And serverdate.getTime(); return's number of Miliseconds of the total time.

You should lear about [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) Object in JavaScript

Comment: Ok, you seem to know what are you talking about :) Now I'm using weekday[currentDay]. But how can I extract time from serverdate?

var hours=serverdate.getHours(); 
...etc?

Comment: You need to Hours + Minutes + Seconds + Miliseconds .

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `currentDay` with `weekday[currentDay]` because you compare with day name. This will works for you.

Comment: I will try your solution first! Will report back if it works! Thank you in advance